# barplot in grid does work for more than 2 plots

Tags: pandas, plot, seaborn

I am trying to group several barplots created with `seaborn` in one single grip. The data is a list of 160 000 songs from 1921 to 2000 and can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks). My barplot identifies the 30 most popular artist of 1) all time 2) 80s 3) 90s and 4) 2000s. I have filtered the datasets:

```
Spotify_2000 = Spotify.loc[Spotify['year'] >= 2000]
Spotify_1990s = Spotify.loc[(Spotify['year'] >= 1990) & (Spotify['year'] < 2000) ]
Spotify_1980s = Spotify.loc[(Spotify['year'] >= 1980) & (Spotify['year'] < 1990) ]
```

and have done this to create the desired output figure:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[30,30])
gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(100,100)

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,0:40])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,60:100])
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,0:40])
ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,60:100])

lead_artists1 = Spotify.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists1.values, y=lead_artists1.index, palette="Blues", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Popularity All time (Count of presence in the dataset Spotify)', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Artist', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_title('30 Most Popular Artists past 100 years', c='w', fontsize=20, weight = 'bold')


lead_artists2 = Spotify_2000.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists2.values, y=lead_artists2.index, palette="Greens", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel('Popularity (Count of presence in the dataset Spotify_2000)', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax2.set_ylabel('Artist', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax2.set_title('30 least Popular Artists 00s', c='w', fontsize=20, weight = 'bold')


lead_artists3 = Spotify_1990s.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)
ax3 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists3.values, y=lead_artists3.index, palette="Greens", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax2)
ax3.set_xlabel('Popularity 1990s (Count of presence in the dataset Spotify_1980s)', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax3.set_ylabel('Artist', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax3.set_title('30 most Popular Artists 90s', c='w', fontsize=20, weight = 'bold')

lead_artists4 = Spotify_1980s.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)
ax4 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists4.values, y=lead_artists4.index, palette="Greens", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax2)
ax4.set_xlabel('Popularity 1980s (Count of presence in the dataset Spotify_1980s)', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax4.set_ylabel('Artist', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax4.set_title('30 most Popular Artists 80s', c='w', fontsize=20, weight = 'bold')

fig1.savefig('C:/Users/k_sego/repos/TOY_jptNB/Graphs/Popularity.png')
plt.show()
```

It works just fine for only two barplots (i.e. removing two in the above and of course fixing the grid distribution). It has nothing to do with the dataframes since I can barplot any of them individually. As soon as I have 4 plots it fails and give the following output:

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what is going on or give me an alternative way to handle this. I could of course, handle them two at a time, but I refuse to believe this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is plotting on `ax2` for the two last data:

```
lead_artists3 = Spotify_1990s.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)

# which axis are you drawing on here?
ax3 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists3.values, y=lead_artists3.index, palette="Greens", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax2)
```

I recommend breaking the long line of code:

```
lead_artists3 = (Spotify_1990s.groupby('artists')
                     ['popularity'].sum()
                     .sort_values(ascending=False)
                     .head(30)
                )

ax3 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists3.values, 
                  y=lead_artists3.index, 
                  palette="Greens", orient="h", 
                  edgecolor='white', ax=ax2)  # <- change this to ax=ax3
```